# Operations on only some values of a column filtered by ANOTHER COLUMN in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[11, 1, 1, 1, 1], [12, 2, 2, 2, 2], [12, 3, 3, 3, 3], [14, 4, 4, 4, 4]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

    a   b   c   d   e
0   11  1   1   1   1
1   12  2   2   2   2
2   12  3   3   3   3
3   14  4   4   4   4
```

I want to exchange values in column 'd' for rows having `value == 12` in column `a`.

Final output should look like this:

```
    a   b   c   d  e
0   11  1   1   1  1
1   12  2   2   3  2
2   12  3   3   2  3
3   14  4   4   4  4
```

How can I achieve this?

I have tried these:

```
df[df["a"] == 12]['d'] = df[df["a"] == 12]['d'].map({2: 3, 3: 2})

df.loc[df.a == 12]["d"].replace({2: 3, 3: 2}, inplace=True)
```

but these do not modify the original dataframe, though we can see changes in the series `df[df["a"] == 12]['d'].map({2: 3, 3: 2})`.

Comment: This might work: `df.d[1], df.d[2] = df.d[2], df.d[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your code? If you use `loc` then, it changes the original one like below.

```py
>>> df.loc[1, 'd'] = 3
>>> df
   a  b  c  d
0  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  3
2  3  3  3  3
3  4  4  4  4
```